# LIMIT 1 by Column On Query Returning Multiple Results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `user_certifications` table, with these props:

```
int user_id
int cert_id
timestamp last_updated
```

So, a user can be listed multiple times with a variety of certs. I have a list of `user_id`s for which I need to get ONLY the most recently updated record. So for one user it would be:

```
SELECT user_id, last_updated 
FROM user_certifications
WHERE user_id == x
ORDER BY last_updated DESC
LIMIT 1
```

How do I do this efficiently if I need ONLY the last dated entry for each of a number of users. E.g. similar query, but `WHERE user_id IN (x,y,z)` and returning one entry per user, with the latest date?

P.S. - I apologize for the title, I don't know how to word this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id), uc.* 
FROM user_certifications uc
ORDER BY user_id, last_updated DESC
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) user_id, uc.*` worked. Link with full explanation here: https://www.geekytidbits.com/postgres-distinct-on/ Thanks a ton Gordon, saved me a ton of time. Will accept once timer expires.